# Rails: Pros and Cons of multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

I'm running a Rails 4 app and have a question about how to structure it. My application has `users`. These users have many fields that can be grouped into categories, such as `Personal Info`, `Work Info`, `Home`, etc.

My question deals with whether I should make separate models for each of these subgroups so `users` have many `has_one` associations, or instead just name the fields in the following fashion: `personal_info_name`, `personal_info_address`, `work_info_address`, etc.

Here are some of my thoughts for grouping into models:

Pros:

- organization
- readibility

Cons:

- takes more database space
- more models means more files/overhead

Is there a "Rails-way" to do this/what are some other pros/cons for having multiple models?

P.S.

I've read a bit about the "fat model, skinny controller" ideas, but am not sure I entirely understand them (if they pertain to the question).

Comment: I think this is more of a database modeling question than a rails one

Comment: How do you recommend I change the tagging/title to reflect that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still use proper `has_one` relations, but utilize ActiveRecord `delegate`s to create shortcut methods:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :personal_info, ...
  has_one :work_info, ...
  delegate :personal_info_name, to: 'personal_info.name'
  delegate :personal_info_address, to: 'personal_info.address'
  delegate :workd_info_address, to: 'work_info.address'
end
```

Of course, assuming you are using Active Record as an ORM. Otherwise, you could go the manual route:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :personal_info, :work_info

  def personal_info_name
    personal_info.name unless personal_info.nil?
  end

  def personal_info_address
    personal_info.address unless personal_info.nil?
  end

  def work_info_address
    work_info.address unless work_info_address.nil?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this is just *one of many ways* of doing it. I usually create a `Profile` model, which belongs to a User. One user can either have one `Profile`, or, if this app is going to grow and allow one User to manage multiple properties, it could have many Profiles later on. Inside these Profiles you can use PGSQL HStore ([tutorial here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/345-hstore)) to store many small preferences (tel1, tel2, address, address_work, etc.) to keep your database from cluttering. Good luck!

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you recommend putting all the fields (working and personal) in a model names `Profile` using the HStore type?

Comment: You can use different hstore fields for work/personal